# [__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa75501220

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to get the json data to a block, but it failed.

1. the Internet request is

   ```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *dataResult, NSError *connectionError) {        
   if (!connectionError) {
       if (successBlock) {
           //NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           //NSLog(@"response data: %@", str);
           NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil];
           successBlock(json);
       }
   } else {
       if (failureBlock) {
           failureBlock(connectionError);
       }
   }
   }];
   ```
2. the successBlock is defined like this:

   ```
   typedef void(^HttpRequestSuccessBlock)(id responseObject);
   typedef void(^HttpRequestFailBlock)(NSError *error);
   ```
3. I can successfully get the `dataResult` in `1` and translate it into NSString, and I `NSlog` it, it is actually the `Json` format.

But when run the code, it crashed and shows the following errors:

```
2017-08-21 09:43:22.258 shopiPhoneDemo[24397:5799646] -[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa75501220
2017-08-21 09:43:22.264 shopiPhoneDemo[24397:5799646] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa75501220'
```

---

Update the stack trace:

```
2017-08-21 09:43:22.258 shopiPhoneDemo[24397:5799646] -[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa75501220
2017-08-21 09:43:22.264 shopiPhoneDemo[24397:5799646] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa75501220'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e8cb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001058f1141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105efc134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e13840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e133b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001054281a1 -[_NSJSONReader findEncodingFromData:withBOMSkipLength:] + 46
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000105428087 -[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] + 58
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000105427fbb +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 139
    8   shopiPhoneDemo                      0x0000000104cc4e2d __24-[AppDelegate youtuTest]_block_invoke + 77
    9   shopiPhoneDemo                      0x0000000104cbfc3f __62-[TXQcloudFrSDK sendRequest:mothod:successBlock:failureBlock:]_block_invoke + 271
    10  CFNetwork                           0x0000000108a045ae __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 161
    11  Foundation                          0x00000001053fb3b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    12  Foundation                          0x00000001053fb0bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    13  Foundation                          0x00000001053f9877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
    14  Foundation                          0x00000001053f55fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010940905c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001093ea40b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e51909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e17ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2164
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e17016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b4bba24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106999134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  shopiPhoneDemo                      0x0000000104cd0eff main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010945565d start + 1
)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

the `Json` NSLog is:

```
{"errorcode":0,"errormsg":"OK","session_id":"","name":"陈佳佳","name_confidence_all":[99,99,99],"sex":"女","sex_confidence_all":[99],"nation":"汉","nation_confidence_all":[99],"birth":"1985/9/11","birth_confidence_all":[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100],"address":"福建省尤溪县汤川乡汤三村16号","address_confidence_all":[99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],"id":"350426198509113027","id_confidence_all":[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100],"frontimage":"","frontimage_confidence_all":[],"watermask_confidence_all":[],"valid_date_confidence_all":[],"authority_confidence_all":[],"backimage_confidence_all":[],"detail_errorcode":[],"detail_errormsg":[]}
```

I use json editor format is:

```
{
"errorcode": 0,
"errormsg": "OK",
"session_id": "",
"name": "陈佳佳",
"name_confidence_all": [
  99,
  99,
  99
],
"sex": "女",
"sex_confidence_all": [
  99
],
"nation": "汉",
"nation_confidence_all": [
  99
],
"birth": "1985/9/11",
"birth_confidence_all": [
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100
],
"address": "福建省尤溪县汤川乡汤三村16号",
"address_confidence_all": [
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99,
  99
],
"id": "350426198509113027",
"id_confidence_all": [
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100
],
"frontimage": "",
"frontimage_confidence_all": [],
"watermask_confidence_all": [],
"valid_date_confidence_all": [],
"authority_confidence_all": [],
"backimage_confidence_all": [],
"detail_errorcode": [],
"detail_errormsg": []
}
```

---

What I have tried to do:

1. I try to make a `mutablecopy` for `json`, but it doesn't working.
2. I try to change the `id` into `NSDictionary`, but it doesn't working either.

Comment: NSDictionary does not have 'bytes' method. Where exactly you have this exception? Can you show a stack trace?

Comment: Show the **JSON** format.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I have updated the question. thanks

Comment: @nayem the **JSON** I have updated

Comment: If you comment json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil]; error is gone or not? and Where are you using this json, please show the code for that

Comment: @user1000 `json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil]` works well, I think `successBlock(json)` causes the errors.

Comment: I think if you do this NSData *receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil]; , then NSLog(receivedData); what is the output?

Comment: @W.LeeLom, It is strange, but your stack trace is disagree with you.

Comment: @user1000 it shows like the nslog in the question. The difference is some key contains `""`, while some not. like this: `birth = "1985/9/11";`, and ` "session_id" = "";`. Because of the limit of length, I cannot put all the nslog in this commet.

Comment: Ok, in your original code if you do this json = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil]; what is the result?

Comment: It crashed the same like before

Comment: Just a side note: Pls consider using NSURLSession since NSURLConnection has been deprecated way back.

Comment: Please, paste the code of the success block.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are dealing with `NSArray` rather than `NSDictionary`. So it's better to handle both of the cases.

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResult options:kNilOptions error:nil];

if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array!");
    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)json;
    NSLog(@"jsonArray - %@",jsonArray);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"its probably a dictionary");
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;
    NSLog(@"jsonDictionary - %@",jsonDictionary);
}
```

Comment: Thanks firstly. The console prints **its probably a dictionary**, when I add `successBlock(json)`, it crashed.

Comment: Include the code from where you are passing the `successBlock` and how are you manipulating the result with that block.

Comment: I have copied the code,  it woks, and pass into `succeBlock`, it can run into this code. In the block, I just want to get the reponse Json.

Comment: Yup, I understand. But what are you doing with that response JSON that you are getting inside your `successBlock`? The problem lies there. You might be doing something related to `bytes` method with your response `NSDictionary`.

Comment: For expamle, the `successBlock` it `TXQcloudFrSDK.m`, this file contains a function `- (void)idcardOcr:(id)image cardType:(NSInteger)cardType sessionId:(NSString *)sessionId successBlock:(HttpRequestSuccessBlock)successBlock failureBlock:(HttpRequestFailBlock)failureBlock`; And I want to use this function in other file like "ABCViewController.m", so I use the `succussBlock`. If I directly use the reponseObject in `TXQcloudFrSDK.m`, it works well. But when pass the `json` into `successBlock`, it failed, and I cannot call this block in  "ABCViewController.m".

Comment: Listen carefully. Your json passing through `successBlock` doesn't fail. What causes problem is ___What you are doing with that passed `JSON`___.

Comment: I am sorry about I didn't catch your meaning well, but thanks for your warmth and your answers. I will try to solve...

Comment: From somewhere in your code you made a call to your `- (void) idcardOcr:cardType:sessionId:successBlock:failureBlock:` right? Show how you made that call.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem inside the data or inside the json parcer. Try to use other json parser with open code, for example  https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/JSONKit.h. You can find, what exactly sends this exception.